# file exists() false negative

Tags: java, file, io, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using commons-vfs 2.1 and it behaves strangely across different environments.

I tested the same piece of code on different environment. And on one environment calling on exists() returns true and on the other returns false. The file is the same and on a remote location. Both environments provide the same credentials.

The environments are different OS's and java version is the same.
Windows 7 (The file exists),
Windows 2012 R2 (file **does not exist**)

```
java.version 1.7.0_71
java.vm.vendor  Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version 24.71-b01
```

I tried digging into the code while debugging both environments the difference I found was at calling file.exists() it calls

```
fs.getBooleanAttributes(this)
```

and for one of them the turned value is **3** and for the other is **0**.

I'm stuck at this point... Looking for any directions to resolve it.

Comment: try `file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()`?

Comment: @DarshanMehta still returns false